# Spring Data JPA - How to query table with no entity class?

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-data-jpa

I am working on below database tables :

- `users` table - Each row represents a User in the system. It has a foreign key constraint to countries table.
- `countries` table - Each row represents a Country and each country can have a list of `dialects` stored in table dialects.

[image]

I am using Spring data JPA and have created below entity classes

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name = "createdAt")
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(name = "country_code")
    private Integer countryCode;

    @Column(name = "dialect_key")
    private String dialectKey;
}

public class Country {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer country_code;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "continent_name")
    private String continentName;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "Dialect", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "country_code") })
    private List<Dialect> dialectList;
}


@Embeddable
public class Dialect {
   private String name;
}
```

Now I have a use case where I need to fetch the `full name` and `dialect name` for a given User.

```
Select u.full_name, d.name from users u
join countries c on u.country_code = c.country_code
join dialects d on c.country_code = d.country_code
where u.id = :user_id and u.dialect_key = d.dialect_key
```

Question - The above query works fine when ran as a native query and returns a List of Object. Further I am mapping the Objects List to the List of POJO. Is there a better way to do this to avoid Object -> POJO conversion explicitly ?

Comment: This are (at least). three questions in one, please decide which you want answered here.

Comment: @JensSchauder - Thanks for the comment. Edited the question accordingly. Meanwhile I got the native query working just that I have to do Object -> POJO conversion explicitly. Is there a better way to do this where this conversion can be avoided?